# How do I deinit a lazy var in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've been reading a bunch about [Swift initilization](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/11/20/swift-initialisation.html) lately, and one solution that appears to have some merit is utilizing lazy variables to avoid the doom and gloom of optionals, especially when extending `UIViewControllers` or other classes along those lines. With that in mind, I've got code that looks like this:

```
final class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    lazy private var myOtherViewController: MyOtherViewController = MyOtherViewController()

    deinit {
        // myOtherViewController = nil // Can't do this. Expression resolves to an unused l-value
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myOtherViewController.foo();
    }
}

// elsewhere...
final class MyOtherViewController : UIViewController {
    deinit {
        print("Deinit!")
    }
}
```

In the example here it **appears** that `MyOtherViewController`'s `deinit` method never seems to fire, but I also have no way to make `myOtherViewController` deinit. Setting it to `nil` isn't allowed. Is there something I'm missing that forces `MyOtherViewController` to retain? Or have I just been impatient with the garbage collector?

Comment: Why do you need to `deinit`? Mostly, according to the docs, you don't, and I don't see why you do given the example...
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html

Comment: It's an architecture question, more than anything else. My goal is to only create objects when I need them and still have control to remove them when they are no longer needed, e.g. a memory warning. Optionals seems like the way to go.

Comment: As an aside, there's something vaguely disquieting about maintaining a strong reference to another view controller. Likewise, I'd advise against instantiating view controllers in a manner that is disconnected from how this controller was added to the view controller hierarchy (e.g. containment calls, presenting, etc.). If you need your own reference to this other view controller, you'd generally have a weak reference, and let the view controller hierarchy take care of the ownership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, your lazy variable would have to be declared as optional even though you intend to initialize it as soon as the value is needed (i.e. lazily).

```
class MyObject {

    func run() {
        print( "MyObject :: run()" )
    }

    init() {
        print( "MyObject :: init" )
    }

    deinit {
        print( "MyObject :: deinit" )
    }
}

class MyContext {
    lazy var myObject:MyObject? = MyObject()
}

let myContext = MyContext()
myContext.myObject?.run()   //< "MyObject :: init"
myContext.myObject = nil    //< "MyObject :: deinit"
```

Also, I disagree with the notion of the "doom and gloom of optionals"—one only need know which of the many available techniques is most convenient and practical way handle them, and how to avoid allowing too many permutations of state to exist among combinations of optional and non-optional values in a given context.  Furthermore, an optional is actually exactly what you want here because you *intend* to nullify it.  Employing an optional doesn't mean that a value will be `nil` for now until you initialize it, but rather that it may be `nil` at any point in its life, even if it is defined at declaration or any other time beforehand.  If avoiding optionals is truly that high of a priority for you, you'd have to take a step back and re-evaluate your architecture to create a situation where you no longer have the need to de-initialize the value.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Grimxn, that this pattern of setting that property to `nil` (and thus needing to make it optional in order to be able to do that) is unnecessary. When `MyViewController` is deallocated, it automatically releases its strong reference to `MyOtherViewController`.

The only time you need to manually `nil` this property is when you have to resolve a strong reference cycle (and if you had such cycle, you can't resolve that in `deinit`, but rather `viewDidDisappear` or something like that).

If you're not seeing this other view controller get deallocated, then I'd suggest finding the source of the strong reference cycle and resolving that.